# MySql query to find the extra column present in second table

Tags: mysql-workbench

We are working on database migration and we are facing a small issue in finding extra columns in second table as below.

First table - **employee_data**

```
col a - id  
col b - name  
col c - age
```

Second table - **employee_data_fp**

```
col a - id  
col b - name
col c - age
col d - address
col e - phoneNo
```

We are trying to merge first and second table by manually adding the extra columns and inserting dataset. Please help to write query to find missed columns.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are planning to build a query using dynamic SQL, you don't really need a query to find the missing columns.  To keep it simple, why not just use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table2;
```

This will echo the create statement to the console.  In addition to revealing the column names, it will also show types, constraints, default values, and a few other potentially useful things.

If you need a query which shows columns unique to the second table which do not appear in the first, then try this:

```
SELECT t2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM
(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourDB' AND
        TABLE_NAME = 'table2'
) t2
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourDB' AND
        TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
) t1
    ON t2.COLUMN_NAME = t1.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE t1.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks tim.. Your suggestion works but we are appending second table with first table. If we keep doing this also may takes more time to compare and add missed out columns.